# How can I get CPU usage value as an integer?

Tags: batch-file, command, cpu-usage, netsh

I ran this batch file:

```
:START
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('typeperf "\processor(_Total)\%% Processor Time" -SC 1 -y ^|find ":" ') DO
(set "var=%%~na"
IF var>=30
(netsh interface teredo set state disabled
netsh interface 6to4 set state disabled
netsh interface isatap set state disabled )
IF var<30
( netsh interface teredo set state client
netsh interface 6to4 set state enabled
netsh interface isatap set state enabled
) )
goto START
```

I want that this program continuosly scans CPU usage percentage, and store that value in an integer 'var'.

Now if CPU usage is more than 30%, I want to disable IPv6. If CPU usage come down to 30%, I want to enable IPv6. I wrote above code, but it is not working. Can you say where is the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by disable `IPV6` - for a particular network card?I dont think `netsh interface 6to4 set state disabled` is exactly disabling.

Answer (score 0):

If your netsh commands are correct then this may work for you:

```
@echo off
:START
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('typeperf "\processor(_Total)\%% Processor Time" -SC 1 -y ^|find ":" ') DO (
echo CPU is at %%a %%
   IF %%~na GTR 30 (
      echo disabling
      netsh interface teredo set state disabled
      netsh interface 6to4 set state disabled
      netsh interface isatap set state disabled 
   ) else (
      echo enabling
      netsh interface teredo set state client
      netsh interface 6to4 set state enabled
      netsh interface isatap set state enabled
   )
)
echo waiting
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
goto :START
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way - with LOGMAN which relies on same [counters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-performance-counters.html) as [typeperf](http://ss64.com/nt/typeperf.html).

With this approach you'll no need of running/looping  batch file - after the code bellow is finished the tasks will start autocratically.

But you'll need to create two additional `.bat` files to enable and disable IPv6 (in this example disable6.bat and enable6.bat).Or at least one additional bat that accepts arguments and use `-targ` key of logman (both LOGMAN and SCHTASKS require admin permissions):

```
@echo off


SCHTASKS /create /tn disable /tr "C:\disable.bat" /sc ONCE /sd 01/01/1910 /st 00:00 
logman stop high_cpu 2>nul & logman delete high_cpu 
logman create alert high_cpu -th "\Processor(_Total)\%% Processor Time>30" -tn "disable"
logman start high_cpu



SCHTASKS /create /tn enable /tr "C:\enable6.bat" /sc ONCE /sd 01/01/1910 /st 00:00
logman stop low_cpu 2>nul & logman delete low_cpu 2>nul  
logman create alert low_cpu -th "\Processor(_Total)\%% Processor Time<30" -tn "enable" 
logman start low_cpu
```

check also [NSPBIND](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2010/01/25/announcing-nvspbind.aspx) tool for disabling IPv6.